# $\left( {\begin{array}{ccc|c} 3 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\ 4 & 4a & 2a & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 2a & 1 \end{array} } \right) a \in \mathbb Z_5$

Tags: matrices

$\left( {\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3 & 1 & 3  & 3 \\
4 & 4a & 2a & 3 \\
2 & 2 & 2a & 1 
\end{array} } \right) a \in \mathbb Z_5$
I would need advice on how to proceed with this example. I need to find and those for which the equation has no solution. I know that in z5 I am limited to the set {0-4} and I try to perform Gaussian elimination
operations.

Comment: Does GEM mean Gaussian elimination?  That's how you do it.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @saulspatz, I would assume Gauss elementary/elimination matrices, or something to that extent.

Comment: If this were over $\Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb Z_5$, would you have been able to do it?

Comment: What exactly is your problem, martin12888? The procedure is the same, you are just working over different field. For example, you would like $1$ to appear at place $(1,1)$ in the matrix. You can achieve it by multiplying the first row by $2$. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The determinant of the matrix is $8 (3 a^2 - 5 a + 3)$, which is zero iff $a \equiv \pm 2 \bmod 5$. So, for $a \equiv 0,1,4 \bmod 5$, the system always has a solution.

Comment: But a determinant of 0, doesn't mean that the system does not have a solution

Comment: @samabu, of course, but it does settle three cases

Comment: Yes, that's true. Just wanted to be sure, there is no missunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Compute the Gaussian elimination. Just take $a$ as it is any number. If this is to difficult, you can use 4 equality systems and check if there is a solution or not (set a=0 and solve then a=1 and solve, ...)